# How to count NULL in COUNT(column) query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table that I'm trying to find the total count for each unique `name` element. The problem is, `other: 1` and `other: Null` are supposed to be different elements, but my query is grouping them together. The issue I'm running into is that `null` is not being counted as a row. But when I use `count(*)`, `other: 1` and `other: Null` are grouped together.

| Name | id | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Other | 1 | 8 |
| Other | Null | 8 |
| Facebook | 2 | 8 |
| Google | 3 | 8 |
| Facebook | 2 | 8 |

The goal is to return:

`[{Other: 1}, {Other: 1}, {Facebook: 2}, {Google: 1}]`

I've tried:

```
SELECT name, count(id) 
FROM table 
WHERE id IS NOT NULL 
AND groupId='${id}' 
GROUP BY name 
UNION 
SELECT name, count(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE id IS NULL 
AND groupId ='${id}' 
GROUP BY name
```

And:

```
SELECT name, count(id)
FROM table
WHERE id='${id}' 
GROUP BY name
```

How would I get the desired return value above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want one result row per name and ID, so don't group by name only, but by name and ID:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE groupId = '${id}' 
GROUP BY name, id
ORDER BY name, id;
```

As you don't want to show the ID in your result, omit it from the select clause.

Answer (score 1):

You're not grouping *by* Id

I think what you need is

```
SELECT name, count(*)
FROM table
WHERE Groupid='${id}' 
GROUP BY name, Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag column that checks if `id` is `null` to group by:

```
SELECT name, 
       id IS NULL null_flag, 
       COUNT(*) count 
FROM tablename 
WHERE groupId = '${id}'  
GROUP BY name, null_flag;
```

Or, if you don't want it in the results:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) count 
FROM tablename 
WHERE groupId = '${id}'  
GROUP BY name, id IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e7e80b5ce5cceab9351bb9b1e2e57754).